# insert value from join with If/Case from two tables, into a third table

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, case, openquery

So I have the following issue in creating a sql query.

A linked server so am using an open query. (edit update: SQL Server)
Two tables as per picture below:

[image]

I need to insert value into a third table, the value to insert to the third table comes from the two  tables above which I join via KEY ID.

However, in the join I want to choose all columns from table A and only Value Code from table B (**there are multiple value codes per Key ID in table B**) so need an if or case depending on the following:

If/Case
Table B has Code = PRODUCT, choose VALUE CODE A,

If there is no Code=PRODUCT, then chose VALUE CODE from code = FOO, in the case of KEY ID 2, that would be VALUE CODE D.

If there is no Code = PRODUCT or no Code = FOO for the given Key ID, then choose VALUE CODE that corresponds to Code = BAR, in this case of Key ID 3 it would be VALUE CODE F.

*Update:*
Sometimes Foo can come before Product in table B, also if there is no correspondence, say there is neither product, foo or bar I wish to return blank in the column row.

How do I write this sql query of join with if/case in a proper way?

Comment: What SQL platform are you using?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what platform you are using, but here is how I would do it in SQL Server

**SQL Server Method**

```
Select a.KeyID,a.[TimeStamp],a.SalesAmount,b.ValueCode
From TableA As a
Outer Apply (
            /*This will grab the top 1 KeyID match, with the sorting you specified based on the code in TableB*/
            Select Top (1) *
            From TableB As tb
            Where a.KeyId = tb.KeyID
            And tb.Code In ('Product','Foo','Bar') /*If only want codes matching the 3 values, then include this line*/
            Order By 
                Case 
                    When tb.Code = 'Product' Then 1
                    When tb.Code = 'Foo' Then 2
                    When tb.Code = 'Bar' Then 3
                    Else 4 /*Pick any other values last*/
                End
        ) As b
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. 
One last question though, say for instance that there is no 'Bar' as tb.Code, then I would like to return ValueCode as blank, how do I do this?

Comment: Clarification, if there is no Product, Foo or Bar in Code table B, then I would like to return Value Code blank/NULL

Comment: Just need to change Cross Apply to Outer Apply. Cross Apply is like an inner join (needs match in both results) and Outer Apply is like a left join. Answer edited accordingly

Comment: Thank you, did that. 
The weird part is that if there is no match with the tb.Code then Value Code becomes whatever is in b.Valuecode as a.KeyId and tb.KeyId match. 

So the outer apply still returns a a non-null record as KeyId matches it seems like thus returning b.ValueCode that's neither Product, Foo or Bar.

Comment: Ah, didn't know there would be codes not in Product, Foo, or Bar. The WHERE clause should fix it if you want only one of the 3. The ELSE clause in the CASE when should handle any exceptions in case you want to include other possible codes not in the list of 3. Answer edited

Comment: I did Else 4 but it still picks a value instead of returning b.ValueCode as NULL, 

Do you know how to write this syntax? Big thanks for your help

Comment: Try adding the line I added `And tb.Code In ('Product','Foo','Bar')`

Comment: That did the trick! You are my hero! Thanks

Comment: I actually had a question I wanted to run by you, could this all have been done with Coalesce as well? Thought I'd ask.

Comment: Not really. Could you join to TableB 3 times (once for each code) then use COALESCE to pick the first value, yes.  But it's convoluted and would be slower. 
Think of it this way, COALESCE runs against 1 row so you need to get your data in 1 row for it to work first. APPLY is designed to do things like grab the first 1 row that is the best match so it's the recommended solution

Answer (score 0):

In any database, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.valuecode
        from b
        where b.keyid = a.keyid and
              b.code in ('Product', 'Foo', 'Bar')
        order by (case code when 'Product' then 1 when 'Foo' then 2 else 3 end)
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as valuecode
from a;
```

You haven't specified the database you are using.  Not all databases support the standard `fetch first` syntax.  Some use `limit` or `select top` or some other method.

I'm also not sure if the `where` clause in the subquery is needed.

Comment: This seems to be for oracle? In my case it's sql (yes, did not mention that originally :) )

Comment: @Johan . . . This is standard SQL, because you didn't specify the database.  You still haven't specified the database and should add it as a tag to the question.  The answer includes alternatives to `fetch first`.